# Well-definedness of $f(x)=\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin{x}}(3+\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin{x}}(3+\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin{x}}(3+\ldots)))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Does there exist an interval $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ which contains more than one element, such that the following function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined?

$$f(x):=\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin{x}}(3+\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin{x}}(3+\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin{x}}(3+\ldots)))$$ for $x\in I$

---

Showing that it is defined on an interval with more than one point seems to be very difficult, as we have to sort of convert this (maybe to a series expression?) first.

I would very much appreciate help, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How is it "surely defined at the point $0$" when setting $x=0$ produces an abundance of $\frac 00$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently we want to have
$$ f(x)=\frac{5\sqrt{2x}}{7\sin x}(3+f(x)).$$
Solving for $f(x)$ gives
$$ f(x)=\frac{15}{7\sin x-5\sqrt{2x}}$$
whenever the denominator is defined and $\ne0$ (which happens to mean: for all $x>0$).

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice approach.